# Apache virtual hosts and config inheritance

Tags: apache-2.4

I have Apache HTTP server set up and running with a bunch of Virtual Hosts which are using Let's Encrypt certificates. However, I can't get sure if global SSL options are inherited by all VHosts.

In main config file (`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) I have the following includes:

```
...

Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include conf/extra/php-fpm.conf

...
```

(the rest of the config isn't shown). So you can see that `httpd-ssl.conf` is included before `httpd-vhosts.conf`. Under each VHost configuration directive I have only references to the valid key/cert pair and `SSLEngine On` option. I wonder if globally-included `httpd-ssl.conf` options are in effect for each VHost, in other words, does VHosts inherit globally-defined options? I can't find any direct clue for this. Or may be should I explicitly include `httpd-ssl.conf` (or Let's Encrypt SSL options file instead) in each VHost directive?

And here arises related question: is there any helper utility to show current configuration for specified VHost including global options as well as defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you need to set/include ssl settings for each individual virtual host?

**No**. When all sites on a server should ***always*** have the same modern security requirements and the same TLS settings then  setting them once in the *"server config"*  context should be sufficient.

Otherwise: **Yes**. When (in the future) an customisation needs to be made in the TLS settings for one of the virtual hosts that override global default values from the server config context; that override could become unintentionally the new default for all other virtual hosts as well.

---

### TL;DR

It depends a bit on the Apache and openssl versions what behaviour you get to see, but for (some) mod_ssl SSL/TLS directives the behaviour is not completely intuitive.

Most Apache mod_ssl settings and directives can indeed be set in the *"server config"*  context and  *"virtual host"*  [context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context),  some are even valid in "directory" and ".htaccess" contexts.
The [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html) lists for each directive where it can be set.

Directive values set in the server config context will be used unless they're  (also) set in a *"virtual host"* context.

The counter intuitive part is that for some settings, when they get a value assigned in "the base virtual host", that value overrides server config for the other virtual hosts.   In other words: for some some settings defined in a virtual host, the scope (effect) was/is not restricted to that particular virtual host.

It's only "explained" in the manual section for the [`SSLProtocol`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol) directive.
(I'm not sure if  I remember correctly and this might also be (or have been)  applicable for other directives such as the `SSLCipherSuite`) :

> ## SSLProtocol for name-based virtual hosts
>
> Before OpenSSL 1.1.1, even though the Server Name Indication (SNI) allowed to determine the targeted virtual host early in the TLS handshake, it was not possible to switch the TLS protocol version of the connection at this point, and thus the `SSLProtocol` negotiated was always based off the one of the base virtual host (first virtual host declared on the listening IP:port of the connection).
>
> Beginning with Apache HTTP server version 2.4.42, when built/linked against OpenSSL 1.1.1 or later, and when the SNI is provided by the client in the TLS handshake, the `SSLProtocol` of each (name-based) virtual host can and will be honored.
>
> For compatibility with previous versions, if no `SSLProtocol` is configured in a name-based virtual host, the one from the base virtual host still applies, unless `SSLProtocol` is configured globally in which case the global value applies (this latter exception is more sensible than compatible, though).

### For example

A main server config configuration with three virtual host blocks:

```
#/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

...


LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 

Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName insecure.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/insecure.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/insecure.example.com.key"
    SSLProtocol All
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName secure.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"
    SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
</VirtualHost>
```

On my old RHEL 7 with openssl 1.0.2 and apache 2.4.6 ; the legacy apache / openssl versions the manual warns about:

- That has the effect that for `www.example.com` ; where the virtual host block has no explicit SSLProtocol defined:  the value `All`  from default host `insecure.example.com`  gets used and not the value main server context `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1`.
- Additionally for `secure.example.com` the explicitly defined `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2` also gets ignored and the value `All`  from default host `insecure.example.com`  gets used instead.

---

Copy that configuration to a modern host with a recent Apache httpd version and openssl that now also supports TLS version 1.3:

- That has the effect that for `www.example.com` ; where the virtual host block has no explicit SSLProtocol defined:   the value from main server context `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1` gets used. In other words after expanding `All`: `SSLProtocol TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2`
- Additionally for `secure.example.com` the explicitly defined `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2` also gets used, but the configuration is not the most secure because it doesn't support the newer TLSv1.3